# Tough mudder "Electroshock therapy" obstacle

Tags: electricity, biophysics, perception

The Tough mudder is an obstacle race where some obstacles test someone's mental grit. One of the obstacles is the "Electroshock therapy" where someone has to run through dangling wires that carry electrostatic voltage up to 10000 volts. Some people told that the electric shocks really hurt.

But 10000 electrostatic volt is a voltage that occur not rarely in everyday life. Even static charging at a carpet by friction can generate 10000 volts or more. Now I have heard that for cow fence generators the typical electroshock energy determines how painful the shocks will be. Some cow fence generators have characteristic jolt energies of 5 joule. The Tough mudder electroshocks I think have only 1 joule for the shocks.

Question: Is an electrostatic discharge with 10000 volts (assuming the equal persion and equal physical conditions) but 5 joule more painful than a discharge with 1 joule (and also 10000 volts)? What electrodynamic quantity affects the most on the percepted shock intensity (is it maintainly the voltage or more amperage or shock energy)? Are there characteristic differences within electric fences (for equal electrostatic voltage)?

Comment: Just FYI, if you tried to get away with an unsafe electrical circuit that could potentially deposit 1-5J of electrical energy in a human body under any circumstances in a well run physics lab, the health and safety people would come after you faster than lightning. My advice: DON'T!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about human perception of electricity, not physics.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage means nothing without knowing the impedance (typically capacitance) of the system since it is the current, not the voltage, that hurts.

This is why it makes more sense to talk about the energy ($\frac12 C V^2$) than just the voltage. Most of these systems have a series impedance and some capacitance - either just from the wire itself, or deliberately added to ensure the right charge pulse is delivered.

The high voltage then ensures that skin impedance is a small factor (relative to everything else in the circuit).

Comment: For such a high voltage the effective resistance of the human body is on the order of approx. $1k\Omega$. At $10kV$ the high impedance outer layer of dead epidermis cells breaks down dielectrically very quickly, leaving the metal electrodes connected to the internal low impedance saline solution of tissue. One can be a bit more specific using electrode configuration and skin effect, but the human body as a whole is remarkably conductive once the discharge burns trough the dry skin. At $10kV$ there better be a current limiting series resistor or inductance or else...

Comment: @CuriousOne I didn't know the 10kV burns a conductive holds in the dermis - but that is why like electric fences, these things are surely pulsed, and charge/current limited. Making the actual pulse delivered more controlled.